# How to set up a Maven respository with expired SSL certificate on Android Studio using Gradle?

Tags: android-studio, ssl, gradle

I am new to Android development, and I am trying to add a Maven repository to my EmptyActivity project the problem is that the repository is under HTTPS but it's certificate has expired. And when I build the project I get an error like this:

> NotAfter: Thu Sep 12 12:27:05 ART 2019

Which is the date when certificate expired

What I have try up to now:

- File -> Settings -> Tools -> Diff & Merge -> Server Certificates -> Accept Non-trusted certificates automatically.
- File -> Settings -> Tools -> Diff & Merge -> Server Certificates -> Added manually the certificate to Accepted Certificates.
- File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart

Here is my Project build.gradle

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://artifactory.url/artifactory/libs-release-local/more/paths/here/"
            credentials {
                username = "${artifactory_username}"
                password = "${artifactory_password}"
            }
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.mygroup:artifact:version'
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Contact the admin of the server and suggest to update the HTTPS certificate.

Comment: There isn't another way?

Comment: I did not say it's the only way, but it is the only correct way to handle such a situation.